# problem showing image in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to show all images from a selected category on screen. Which is the best way to accomplish this? because the drawable folder won't allow me to create subfolders :( 
i will be using a database but i don't want to save the whole image in it, can this be done?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the database to store the resource name of each image associated with its category.

When you want to display all images from a particular category, you can `SELECT resourceName FROM images WHERE category = 'plants'`. Then iterate over the returned cursor, using the resource name (which is the ID of the drawable) to load from the drawable folder as you would normally.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Thanks for sharing your experience ;)